# How to call a component from inside useCallback hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a button component which when clicked should render a modal to the screen, but for some reason it seems not to work, here’s my implementation

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { OverflowMenuItem } from '@carbon/react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { AddItemToListModal } from '@myLib/commons-lib';

const AddToListOverflowMenuItem = ({ patientUuid }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => AddItemToListModal, []);

  return (
    <OverflowMenuItem
      itemText={t('addToList')}
      onClick={handleClick}
      style={{
        maxWidth: '100vw',
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default AddToListOverflowMenuItem;
```

Comment: `AddItemToListModal` what is this? If it's a component, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Where would this to component mount and render to? What is `AddItemToListModal`? Do you get warnings or errors in the console when you do this action?

Comment: @evolutionxbox AddItemToListModal is the modal I want to render on the screen when when the handleClick is run

Comment: @Harrison I need the AddItemToListModal component to render on my screen when I click on the AddToListOverflowMenuItem component which is the functional component being returned above, pardon my bad use of naming conventions...

Answer (score 2):

```
const AddToListOverflowMenuItem = ({ patientUuid }) => {
        const { t } = useTranslation();
        const handleClick = useCallback(() => AddItemToListModal, []);
        const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <OverflowMenuItem
                    itemText={t('addToList')}
                    onClick={() => setIsVisible(true)}
                    style={{
                        maxWidth: '100vw',
                    }}
                />
                <AddItemToListModal isVisible={isVisible} />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };

    export default AddToListOverflowMenuItem;
```

With modal I'd normally work with some `isVisible` state that is set locally like that.. a modal can/should already be nested in the tree. This is just a basic example to show.. you'll need to device how to hide and handle this prop inside your modal component

Comment: So `handleClick` is unneeded here?

Comment: yes, you would not need that. Another example here -> https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-a-pop-up-modal-in-react-native/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you declare and use your function inside the useCallback. You're doing it wrong.

To make it work, simply change your useCallback to be like this:

```js
const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
 AddItemToListModal();
}, []);
```

The useCallback first argument explanation:

> fn: The function value that you want to cache. It can take any
> arguments and return any values. React will return (not call!) your
> function back to you during the initial render. On next renders, React
> will give you the same function again if the dependencies have not
> changed since the last render. Otherwise, it will give you the
> function that you have passed during the current render, and store it
> in case it can be reused later. React will not call your function. The
> function is returned to you so you can decide when and whether to call
> it.

For more information:
https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback